# Show div #2 while hovering relative div #1 with translition effect in one container

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a little problem with this: http://jsfiddle.net/eyy0c4uf/
I would like to do the following.

`image-logo` will be hidden untill user hover over the `main-image`. I also would like to have another hover effect for `image-logo`while the `main-image` hover effect is keept.

CSS/HTML/JS solutions only.

Thanks

Comment: You can't hover both `.image-logo` **and** `.main-image`.

Comment: Okay, isn't there any way to have it correct, e.g. using background-image?

Comment: I'm not sure what effect you're looking to achieve; I provided one suggestion as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is based on the inferred intent of the author after looking at their attached code.*

You cannot hover two siblings at the same time, but you can cause a delayed *snapback* from a hover.

```css
.logo-image {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 10000s, box-shadow 2s;
}

.main-image:hover + .logo-image {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.logo-image:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2em rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

The transition delay on `.logo-image` will cause it to retain its second state for 10000 seconds. This number is arbitrarily chosen - we just need it to last a while.

So you only need to hover the `.main-image` element, which then reveals its sibling. The sibling has its own `:hover` state that can then be interacted with.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/eyy0c4uf/3/

Fair warning, **this is a hack**. I don't suggest you *rely* on an approach like this. Instead, identify the effect you're looking to achieve, and make the appropriate markup/scripting changes needed to appropriately satisfy that need.

This answer is merely a demonstration that this is, in some way, possible with CSS alone.

Comment: I just want to create a box(image) which shows button(in it) when hovering over it.

Comment: Exactly! but I want a hover effect for background image. Just did it using background-image instead of absolute's.

Comment: You want to change the element's `background` property when it element is in its `:hover` state? If so, you should be able to do so from the code I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery function that you need. Don't forget to declare the jQuery in your header
http://jsfiddle.net/eyy0c4uf/4/

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function ( $ ) {
    $( ".main-image" ).hover(
        function () {
            $( ".logo-image" ).css( 'display', 'block' );
        }, 
        function () {
            $( ".logo-image" ).css( 'display', 'none' );
        }
    );
    $( ".logo-image" ).hover(
        function () {
            $( ".logo-image" ).css( 'display', 'block' );
        },
        function () {
            $( ".logo-image" ).css( 'display', 'none' );
        }
    );
});
```

This is an example of jQuery hover effect. Let me know if you want something more.

EDIT: I fixed a little bug that happens when you hover .logo-image

Comment: Thanks, I am not a huge fan of jQuery. Any possiblities with js or by using background-image instead of main-image ?

Comment: I can't see a way of doing it just by using a background image right now. Let me think a bit